# Ruby : return key on 'gets' shows '^M' character

Tags: ruby

return key on `gets` shows `^M` character.

Is this Ruby's specification?

```
[1] pry(main)> gets
foo^M # type f, o, o, return, then ctrl-j
=> "foo\r\n"
[2] pry(main)> gets
bar # type b, a, r, then ctrl-j
=> "bar\n"
```

edit:

I'm using Mac OSX, and Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: Need to reset your terminal. Like so: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79686.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting my Mac, 'new line' is gotten by 'return key'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'ts because you'r working on Windows :

- \r\n = CR + LF a new line character in Windows
- \r => CR (Carriage Return) a new line character in MacOS
- \n => LF (Line Feed) a new line character in Unix/ OSX

  ^M => \r\n

look at this way :

```
[1] pry(main)> gets.chomp
foo    (return or ctrl+j)
=> "foo"
```

Comment: No, I'm using Mac OSX.